# what is the best way to process multi files in storm

Tags: similarity, apache-storm

I am new apache storm, i want to use storm to get similarity of files. I want get cosine of all of file in folder "A" with all of file in folder "B". can you help me to show the way to get result.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Asking for "the best way" invites opinions and discussion and exposes the question to being labeled "off topic." Try asking for examples of working code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you meant by 'cosine of all files', but in general,
you can think of each folder as a 'stream'. You can have spoutA that read-understand-format-emit the files in folderA and spoutB that does the same for folderB into two tuple streams (I am assuming there are some differences between the two folders like encoding, formatting etc.). Your processing bolt can then 'subscribe' to those streams. For e.g.,

```
bolt.fieldsGrouping(spoutA, streamname, new Fields("field_in_stream"));
bolt.fieldsGrouping(spoutB, streamname, new Fields("field_in_stream"));
```

If on the other hand, you meant something like two different instances of the same spout to read from different folders

- Not a great idea, because the number of spout executors is now
  tied to the #folders you have. Not scalable.
- Load distribution will probably be pretty bad.
- If you still want to do it, you can
  use the task-index of a spout to have different spout executors with
  slightly different behavior (different meaning reading from different folders)

Like this, maybe

```
public class MySpout extends BaseRichSpout {
     public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
                SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
                System.out.println("Spout Index = " + context.getThisTaskId());
           }
     }
```